# How-to define array of generic elements

Tags: arrays, generics, ada

With help from many sources, I have a working generic thing for a ring-buffer, with push and read of single elements:

q.ads:

```
generic
    Q_SIZE : POSITIVE;
    type T is private;
package Q is
    subtype SIZE_TYPE is NATURAL range 0 .. Q_SIZE;
    subtype Q_INDEX_TYPE is SIZE_TYPE range 1 .. SIZE_TYPE'last;
    type Q_ARRAY_TYPE is array (Q_INDEX_TYPE) of T;

    procedure INITIALIZE;
    procedure PUSH(element : T);
    function READ return T;
end Q;
```

q.adb:

```
package body Q is
    Q_ARRAY : Q_ARRAY_TYPE;
    TAIL : Q_INDEX_TYPE;
    HEAD : Q_INDEX_TYPE;
    ...
end Q;
```

My test program instantiates the above for bytes and exercises the ring.  It is basically as follows:

```
package body main is
    package RING is new Q (15, UNSIGNED.BYTE);
    procedure TEST is
        byteval : UNSIGNED.BYTE;
    begin
        byteval := 16;
        RING.PUSH(byteval);
  ...
```

I would now like to add the ability to pass an array of T in.  I've add this to the ADS and ADB files:

```
    procedure PUSH_ARRAY(DATA_ARRAY : Q_ARRAY_TYPE; COUNT : SIZE_TYPE);
```

My problem is in the test program.  I've changed it to this:

```
    BYTE_ARRAY : array (1 .. 10) of UNSIGNED.BYTE;
    procedure TEST is begin
        -- initialize the first 5 elements of BYTE_ARRAY, then
        RING.PUSH_ARRAY(BYTE_ARRAY, 5);
```

this last line gives me an error message: expected type Q_ARRAY_TYPE defined at Q.ADS:xx.  How do I pass a BYTE ARRAY to my method which expects an instance of the generic array?

Comment: BYTE_ARRAY needs to be a Q_ARRAY_TYPE. With the current generic declaration, that means same size as well as same elements. Perhaps Q_ARRAY_TYPE needs to become an UNconstrained array (with the constraints applied at the time of a variable's declaration)? As in `type Q_ARRAY_TYPE is array (<>) of T;` and `BYTE_ARRAY : Ring.Q_ARRAY_TYPE ( 1 .. 10);`

Comment: @Brian - great idea.  Unfortunately the definition of Q_ARRAY_TYPE as you show gives me error: Identifier expected.  At column 32, which is ...array (HERE<>)...  Using GnatPro 6.2.2 with Ada95

Comment: ah, I meant `type Q_ARRAY_TYPE is array (Q_INDEX_TYPE range <>) of T;` sorry.

Comment: If you do that, `PUSH_ARRAY` could do without the `COUNT` parameter.

Comment: Parameters in a formal parameter list are separated with `;` in Ada, not `,`.  Was this a typo in your program, or in the question?

Comment: @ajb -- thanks for spotting that.  It was not the reason for the question.  It was the fact that I had BYTE_ARRAY, not Q_ARRAY_TYPE.  I think brian's comment is the solution

Comment: @brian - The data is coming from a socket read call in an array of unsigned.byte.  With the queue having to be a Q_ARRAY_TYPE, is there any way I can cast it, or do I really need to do for loop and copy the bytes from one array to the other?

Comment: One way is to instantiate the generic function `UNCHECKED_CONVERSION` with the two array types, and call that when passing the byte array an a Q_ARRAY_TYPE to Push_Array. One of the few times I like to use ALL CAPS, to make it stand out in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Question:  What is the purpose of `SIZE_TYPE`?
In Ada, the `'Length` attribute will return the size of the array in `Natural` (the nonnegative Integer subtype). With that in mind, it doesn't seem to make sense to declare an extra subtype with an extra value for the index.

---

`Ring_Buffer.ads`

```ada
Generic
   Type T is private;
   Default : T;
   Size    : Positive;
Package Ring_Buffer is

   SubType Index is Positive range 1..Size;

   Type Ring is private;

   Function  Length( Obj : Ring ) return Natural;

   Function  Pop( Obj : in out Ring ) return T
     with Pre  => Length(Obj) in Positive,
          Post => Length(Obj'Old)-1 = Length(Obj); --' --Highlight fix

   Procedure Push( Obj : in out Ring; Item : in T )
     with Pre  => Length(Obj) < Size,
          Post => Length(Obj'Old)+1 = Length(Obj); --'

Private
   Type Internal_Data is Array(Index) of T;
   Type Ring is record
      Start : Positive:= Internal_Data'First; --'
      Size  : Natural:= 0;
      Data  : Internal_Data:= (Others => Default);
   end record
   with Type_Invariant => Ring.Size <= Size;

   Function Length( Obj : Ring ) return Natural is
      ( Obj.Size );

End Ring_Buffer;
```

`Ring_Buffer.adb`

```ada
Package Body Ring_Buffer is

   Function  Pop( Obj : in out Ring ) return T is
   Begin
      return Result : constant T := Obj.Data(Obj.Start) do
         Obj.Size:= Natural'Pred( Obj.Size ); --'
         Obj.Start:= (if Obj.Start = Size then 1 else Obj.Start + 1);
      end return;
   End Pop;

   Procedure Push( Obj : in out Ring; Item : in T ) is
   Begin
      Obj.Data( Natural'Succ((Obj.Start-1) + Obj.Size mod Size) ):= Item; --'
      Obj.Size:= Obj.Size + 1;
   End Push;

End Ring_Buffer;
```

Comment: Yeah, I understand, except that the TCP receiver that fills the array only partially fills it and returns a count how much is returned.  So the size_type is useful.  The real problem though is the fact that you can't load an array of bytes into an array of generic of byte without calling unchecked_conversion, which does a copy.  In the end I decided to just do a loop and call PUSH repeatedly...